# If generic extends interface, require all the arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a set of interfaces, and a Generic interface.
This generic interface, can potentially extend any interface in the set of interfaces, but if it does, I want it to require all the values in the extended interface

```js
interface one {
   b: boolean,
   c: number
}

interface two {
   d: string[]
   f: boolean[]
}

function F<K>(p : K) =>.....
```

I would actually have something like 
`K extends one & two`

But this should be an error:

```
const a = {b: true, c:2, d:["as"]}
F(a)
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPYhQbwLAChkEBGAXMoaqgDYRwgA0eByCpIArgLaHR4C+eeUJFiIUYAO6pkOfAQAmpAM5gooAOYBtALqMCMUuSo0Q2vgNww2IBGGDpkAMQA8AaWQQAHpBBzFaDMgAPsgSUgB8ABQADsikLgCUMgQI6IpGAHSUqGrR8Wa4eCkgyshwyAC80iQhUGwQdMzEAEwNChoARHCK7Vr8uA4RcPFAA

Comment: Your playground example is different from your code here. It does not contain `f` in `two`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? `function F<K extends one & two >(p : K)` works fine for me.

Comment: Updated the link. I would like an error, since the interface 2 is not fully implemented, and 
`const a = {b: true, c:2}` 
should not be an error, since one is fully implemented

Comment: So you want it to take either interface one, or interface two, or both? But not something “in between”?

Comment: Exactly, and the set of interfaces could be N, so ... one, two, three, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm renaming your types to make them more conventional:

```
interface One {
  b: boolean;
  c: number;
}

interface Two {
  d: string[];
  f: boolean[];
}
```

One of the issues here is that types in TypeScript are *extendible* and not [*exact*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  So the value `{b: true, c:2, d:["as"]}` is a perfectly valid instance of `One | Two`, since it is assignable to `One`.  Normally you'd get [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) to warn you about `d`, but since `d` is part of `Two`, the compiler won't see that as an excess property.

One idea would be to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to say "something with none of the properties of T", like this:

```
type NoneOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: never };
```

So then `NoneOf<One>` would be `{b?: never, c?: never}` and `NoneOf<Two>` would be `{d?: never, f?: never}`.  Then the type you're looking for would be

```
type DesiredType = (One | NoneOf<One>) & (Two | NoneOf<Two>);
```

And you could see it work:

```
const a: DesiredType = {b: true, c:2, d:["as"]};  // error
const okay: DesiredType = {b: true, c: 2}; // okay
```

---

But you said you wanted to have N interfaces, like say

```
interface Three {
  g: number[];
  h: string;
}
```

And you want something programmatic, I guess, that turns (`One | Two | Three | Four | ...`) into `(One | NoneOf<One>) & (Two | NoneOf<Two>) & (Three | NoneOf<Three>) & (Four | NoneOf<Four>) & ...`.  This is possible, use a variant of [a solution to turn unions into intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218):

```
type UnionToAllOrNone<U> = (U extends any
  ? (k: U | NoneOf<U>) => void
  : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
  ? I
  : never;
```

And then let's see it work with `One | Two | Three`:

```
type I = UnionToAllOrNone<One | Two | Three>;

function f(i: I) {}

f({}); // none of them
f({ b: true, c: 1 }); // just One
f({ d: [""], f: [true] }); // just Two
f({ g: [1], h: "" }); // just Three
f({ b: true, c: 1, d: [""], f: [true] }); // One and Two
f({ b: true, c: 1, d: [""], f: [true], g: [1], h: "" }); // One, Two, Three
```

Those are all accepted, while the following is rejected:

```
f({ b: true, c: 1, d: [""] }); // error! 
/* 
 Argument of type '{ b: true; c: number; d: string[]; }' 
 is not assignable to parameter of type '(One & Two & Three) | 
 (One & Two & NoneOf<Three>) | (One & NoneOf<Two> & Three) | 
 (One & NoneOf<Two> & NoneOf<Three>) | (NoneOf<One> & Two & Three) | 
 (NoneOf<One> & Two & NoneOf<...>) | 
 (NoneOf<...> & ... 1 more ... & Three) | 
 (NoneOf<...> & ... 1 more ... & NoneOf<...>) 
*/
```

The error message might be a bit cryptic, since it basically is a union of 2-to-the-power-of-N intersections, but hopefully it's good enough.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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-KAhfHEACMg3bJKhACtmBZ3IPllVZNU4slwjpqr91NOO-PF48fCuqqzqhP1OEechNwfZ8gFxYC0yz8OgqO-gSJzFiPEtxrf89wfUk1moaRvHEd9cS-cdkF-QF-03a8gN3L9UIvVQrxvYh7zbQ80AwcIfBIwsIF4IdYLHCIEL-DdklAqEYRcABCZBsHBAAqDjkBsKBlDYd1Hh7UYUAAciqaiIDBAkWHYTgkOQBQlBANRNEGcTeOAbUrEeRJpmUEA4HwSgggkTI4CgOBWAgAQyXaMTkHE1Yc2OM53PIg4vFwVyUHc8QjguM1rnI-Zzj8oLLm2G4gtfItvN4yLjmi65xHKFKQpKMLEuWVLs2LOLAs8plEt8-LdiKiRMq2YoADoGvCnyTnyhq6oy5A2oQ5BWBcFAupKhLznKrK2o6rqp162ZOoaqLRsag5sC48FKVW3ggA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciated it. Would you mind explaining a little bit more why `& (Two | NoneOf<Two>)` this works

Comment: Are you aware of how [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) and [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) work?  `A | B` means either `A` or `B` (and this is an *inclusive* "or", since something which is both an `A` and a `B` is a valid `A | B`), and `A & B` means both an `A` and a `B`.  Since types are not exact, `One & Two` means it has the properties from `One` and the properties from `Two`.

Comment: So, something assignable to `(One | NoneOf<One>) & (Two | NoneOf<Two>)` must either be a `One` or a `NoneOf<One>`, and it also must be either a `Two` or a `NoneOf<Two>`.  That is the type you want to describe... it either has all or none of the properties of `One`, and all or none of the properties of `Two`.  Does that make sense to you?